# OpenCV read image from csv file

Tags: opencv, csv

I have image in csv file and i want to load it in my program. I found that I can load image from cvs like this:

```
CvMLData mlData;
mlData.read_csv(argv[1]);
const CvMat* tmp = mlData.get_values();
cv::Mat img(tmp, true),img1;

img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);
cv::namedWindow("img");
cv::imshow("img", img);
```

I have RGB picture in that file but I got grey picture...  Can somebody explain me how to load color image or how can I modify this code to get color image?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe show us the first 4-5 lines of your CSV file so we can see what is going on?

Comment: Tnx for response.... CSV is made from color picture.I just print in file Mat object in which i loaded color picture. File has 177 rows and 852 cols...  I done it by code :     
Mat image;
image = imread( argv[1], 1 );cout << image <<endl; and redirect output to file. Later, i use that file in above program.

Comment: So please show us the first 4-5 lines.

Comment: File is here :  http://www.filedropper.com/izlaz

Comment: You say you got a grey picture - do you mean a blank grey screen with no discernible content, or a greyscale image that is recognisable as the greyscale version of your colour image?

Comment: i got greyscale image :)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Ok, I don't know how to read your file into OpenCV for the moment, but I can offer you a work-around to get you started. The following will create a header for a `PNM` format file to match your CSV file and then append your data onto the end and you should end up with a file that you can load.

```
printf "P3\n284 177\n255\n"  > a.pnm     # Create PNM header
tr -d ',][' < izlaz.csv     >> a.pnm     # Append CSV data, after removing commas and []
```

If I do the above, I can see your bench, tree and river.

If you cannot read that `PNM` file directly into OpenCV, you can make it into a JPEG with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert a.pnm a.jpg
```

I also had a look at the University of Wisconsin ML data archive, that is read with those OpenCV functions that you are using, and the format of their data is different from yours... theirs is like this:

```
1000025,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1002945,5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,2
1015425,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
1016277,6,8,8,1,3,4,3,7,1,2
```

yours looks like this:

```
[201, 191, 157, 201 ... ]
```

So maybe this `tr` command is enough to convert your data:

```
tr -d '][' < izlaz.csv > TryMe.csv
```

**Original Answer**

If you run the following on your CSV file, it translates commas into newlines and then counts the lines:

```
tr "," "\n" < izlaz.csv  | wc -l
```

And that gives 150,804 lines, which means 150,804 commas in your file and therefore 150,804 integers in your file (+/- 1 or 2). If your greyscale image is 177 rows by 852 columns, you are going to need 150,804 RGB triplets (i.e. 450,000 +/- integers) to represent a colour image, as it is you only have a single greyscale value for each pixel.

The fault is in the way you write the file, not the way you read it.

Comment: Than you for answer, but... My csv file has 852 columns becouse image has 284 columns, so 284*3=852 numbers in line... I made file from color image, just print matrix representation in file, with command : cout << image <<endl;

Comment: Thank you for answer... this could be good solution if i want just to load image. But in my problem i must load image from csv using  opencv or c++ commands... so i am still looking for solution :(

Answer (score 0):

To see color image I must set number of channels. So this code works for me:

```
CvMLData mlData;
mlData.read_csv(argv[1]);
const CvMat* tmp = mlData.get_values();
cv::Mat img(tmp, true),img1;
img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);
img= img.reshape(3); //set number of channels
```